# Assign part of a string to a variable [Python]

Tags: python, string

So I have the string:

```
[53,2]
```

And I want to seperate it so that:

```
x = 52
y = 2
```

Comment: Do you have `[53, 2]`, or do you have `"[53, 2]"`? `[53, 2]` is a list, `"[53, 2]"` is a string.

Comment: Have you been through the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html)?

Comment: Separating `[53, 2]` into its two elements, 53 and 2, won't produce 52 and 2.  You might need some math, or maybe the question has an error in the wording.  I can not tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling it a string, but the syntax says it's a list; so I'll answer both :).

If it's a string, you can make it a list by doing:

```
data = "[53, 2]"
data_stripped = data.strip('[]')  # remove '[' and ']'s from the ends
data_split = data.split(',')  # split into a list containing each entry
data_final = [int(x) for x in data_split]  # convert strings to ints
```

At this point `data_final` contains the list `[53, 2]`. If your initial value was a list already, you can skip the above code and just assign it to `data_final` before running the following code:

```
x, y = data_final
```

That's it! :)

**EDIT:**

Another way to parse the string would be to use `json.loads`:

```
import json

data_str = '[53, 2]'

data = json.loads(data_str)
```

`data` will then be the list `[53, 2]`. Then you can get `x` and `y` the same way as above:

```
x, y = data
```

Thanks to _habnabit in the #python IRC channel on FreeNode for pointing this out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Easy!

```
X, y = [53, 2]
```

Isn't Python fun?

If your object is actually a string and not a list, you can safely convert it to a list:

```
import ast
x, y = ast.literal_eval("[53, 2]")
```

Comment: For those who are wondering, `ast.literal_eval()` is safe to use even on untrusted input, as opposed to `eval()`. DO NOT use `eval`!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a string and not an array/list you will need [replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) and [split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) methods.

```
mystring="[53,2]"

x=str.split(mystring,",")[0].replace("[","")
y=str.split(mystring,",")[1].replace("]","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
a=[53,2]

x=a[0]
y=a[1]

print(x,y)
53 2
```

**Edit:** Sorry, misread your question. The numbers are string values.